# What does WINE really stand for?

Tags: wine

I know that this is not exactly the right place to ask, but it's the only place I know where it is at least sort-of-a-good-place to ask.

I have already googled and searched here, but I got multiple conflicting answers. One of them said "WINdows Emulator", another said "WINE Is Not an Emulator" (which is kind of strange seeing its nature and general description), and I thought of it meaning "Windows Internal Native Emulator".

So what is the REAL answer?

Comment: See http://winehq.org/ to get information about what Wine is.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/42248/is-wine-an-emulator-or-compatibility-layer

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463728/how-wine-windows-programme-loader-works-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29):

> The name Wine initially was an acronym for **Windows emulator**.  Its meaning later shifted to the recursive backronym, **Wine is not an emulator** in order to differentiate the software from CPU emulators

From [WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/about/)

> Wine (originally an acronym for "**Wine Is Not an Emulator**")